# Facebook Integration using ruby on rails by using koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

i want to integrate facebook login to ruby on rails project with the help of Koala. I followed the http://udooz.net/blog/2011/02/facebook-app-using-rails-koala/ sepecified tutorial link. But after installed the koala gem it's not showing the bundle list. More even if i run the rails server it's giving me the following kind of error message:

```
C:/sample/facebook/config/initializers/koala.rb:10:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Koala (NameError)
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/sample/facebook/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/sample/facebook/config.ru:4:in `require'
```

Comment: Paste the contents of your koala.rb initializer

Comment: Refer this http://railsfornovice.wordpress.com/?s=koala

Answer (score 0):

I get this to pass by commenting out the

```
config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
config.gem "koala"
```

from my config/environment.rb file

but then now when I click the login with facebook link for oauth, I get "Csrf detected" error from Devise.

Did you get this working?